# Starting process from service as windows login user

Tags: c#, service, process

I have a process that I want to start from within a service. The service runs under Local System account because the password of users changing every 3 months. The process is not working when it starts with Local System account so it must be running under windows login user.
Of course I cannot enter the user password inside the service because it is changing.
Is there a way to start the process under the login user?
I didn't find if there is a way to use WindowsIdentity with StartInfo.
Thank you

Comment: Why it needs to be started by service? Consider to start it from Windows Scheduler on user' logon instead

Comment: A better place to ask this might be at https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ever since [Windows Vista](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services), Services are barred from accessing the Desktop (they do not have a interaactive session). While you can override that, it is not adviseable to do so. You can still start a Programm with a interactive session from the Service, using the [Process class](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later/). But as you said, without a user account this will not help you.

Also with Vista we got the [Windows Task Scheduler 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler#Task_Scheduler_2.0). It is quite advanced and can do stuff on logon (with the login users credential). A whole bunch of opeartions previous done by services actually got moved into the Sheduler. https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html

Comment: Thank you.
The problem that I need to solve is that the process stopped randomly every few days. I want to check every minute or so that it is running and restart it.
When I started to think on a fix I didn't think that to start it from a service would be such a problem.

Comment: @TamirBerger: What you should be doing is debugging *why* it breaks. If you lack the debugging information, I can give you my favourite two articles on exception handling: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET Those help a lot getting usefull Debugging information.

Comment: @TamirBerger: As for your problem: Just make a Background task that watches for the main programm. No reason to use the Service Manager for resarting.